# Chrome does not detect debugger if attached after process start

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, web-inspector

When I start an Express server with the `--inspect` option, I can navigate to [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) and launch a debug console for the appropriate Remote Target. But, when I start the process without the `--inspect` option, then try to initiate the inspector with `kill -10 $PID`, Chrome does not detect the Remote Target, even though the server indicates that the debugger was started. Is there anything I can do to connect to this process by Chrome or some other means?

This is the output from the server after running `kill -10 $PID`:

```
Attaching to nodejs
nodejs         | Running version 3 on http://0.0.0.0:5000
nodejs         | Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/c948d085-0491-4cd9-9832-a0f0cf120e11
nodejs         | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

**Another note:** I am running this app in a container with a Docker bridge network, but I don't see why that should make a difference because the `--inspect` option registers the same output when I start the server with it.

**Versions:**
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
Node v12.22.1
express@4.17.1

**Additional note:** the procedure I'm describing (starting debug session after server start) is described here: nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

> But, when I start the process without the --inspect option, Chrome does not detect the Remote Target

If you started a process without `--inspect` it is expected that you won't be able to debug your code. Make sure that that logs you are talking about are the latest and some junk from past runs before you removed `--inspect` flag

Comment: Wish that were it. The container stops and gives fresh logs on every startup. I send the `10` command (`USR1`) and see logs added indicating the debugger is started.

Comment: Are you sure that you have rebuilt your containers after the changes?

Comment: there's not much to change. The port is exposed from the Docker file in both cases. In one case, the "inspect" flag is passed, and I can connect to the debugger immediately. In the other, the inspect flag is not passed, and I try to connect by sending a signal to the Node process after it starts, as per the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/ . The server logs show success, yet Chrome does not detect the publication. In any event, I think I've managed to achieve the larger goal through other means. Thank you!